Getting "heater bed not heating at expected rate" error when trying to print PETG on a glass bed
I have an Ender 3 Pro with the BigTreeTech SKR mini E3 motherboard and a glass bed, and I use Klipper running on a Pi.  About a month ago it started giving me the "heater bed not heating at expected rate" error and stopping during warmup. I was trying to print at 80 °C. I replaced the bed heater and thermistor, but got the same error. It would successfully start printing if I lowered the temp to 75 °C, but the PETG wouldn't stick to the bed.
I added the following to my printer.cfg without improvement:
[verify_heater heater_bed] check_gain_time: 80
Yesterday I changed back to a magnetic print bed and it is printing at 80 °C.
Any idea what is going on, and why is it happening now (it used to work fine)?

I'm not yet familiar with Klipper, but this sounds as if the PID for the bed may be off. Please check that, or ignore my comment if not applicable! Just trying to help!

Are you using something on the glass for a bed fixative? I encountered this when testing diluted PVA glue on glass for my Ender 5 Plus. The evaporation of the water from the glue was enough to slow the bed heating to the point that it raised this same error.

When termistor is out of position the temperature reading may vary from 5 to 15°C, so this could affect the time heating even if the temperature is above of displayed on screen. The verifying time 80 is to check if the printer heats as your room temperature spectation, but you can change to check againg after 90 seg, or 95 or 60. Once you know how your variables are affecting.
